# Applying CSS properties to an ID is being ignored - causes?

Tags: css

I have a joomla site (though this post is more broadly about CSS), which has a rather convoluted structure of nested divs. Part of the page has an id #rt-showcase. I have a banner there which gets placed with a paragraph element automatically entered, and there is a bottom margin I am trying to get rid of (http://dev.pfp-consortium.org/). This paragraph element has margins that I am trying to override. The joomla structure is

```
<div id="rt-showcase">
     <div class="rt-showcase-pattern">
        <div class="rt-container">
            <div class="rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega">
                <div class="rt-block ">
                    <div class="module-surround">
                        <div class="module-content">
                            <div class="custom"  >
                                <p><img src="/images/headerimgs/topimage.jpg" alt="topimage" /></p>
```

In firebug I see the p property, which appears part of a compiled CSS file. I cleared CSS cache and added the following in the my theme's CSS:

```
p#rt-showcase { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

But no matter what I do, this declaration is ignored. I thought such a declaration would give the right specificity and take precedence over any other declarations that might be made for other elements in this nested structure.

Any ideas? Incidentally, I figured out how to prevent joomla from adding the p tag, but now I really just want to understand why my CSS edits are not working...

Comment: You apply your CSS definitions to an element that matches `p#rt-showcase`, which must be a `<p id="rt-showcase">` element as specified in your selector. Also, on the website link you provided, there is no `<p>` tag surrounding the `<img>`.

Answer (score 1):

`rt-showcase` is a `div` element. You describe CSS selector for `p` element.

It should be:

```
div#rt-showcase { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You apply your CSS definitions to an element that matches `p#rt-showcase`, which must be a `<p id="rt-showcase">` element as specified in your selector. Also, on the website link you provided, there is no `<p>` tag surrounding the `<img>`.

According to the code you provided you want to target a `<p>` element that is a deeply nested child element of `<div id="rt-showcase">`. To do that, use the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors):

```
#rt-showcase p {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Please note that this will affect ***all*** `<p>` elements that occur inside `<div id="rt-showcase">`.

If for some reason you must avoid this, add the class of the direct parent element to the selector:

```
#rt-showcase .custom p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I was able to remove the p element as none of the solutions were working. I put it back, and indeed your solution works. I think I understand this better now, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Pick your answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

That is a div not a paragraph.

Try:

```
div#rt-showcase { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

if you want to apply it to a child element:

```
#rt-showcase > p  { 
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have

```
div#rt-showcase { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Because the element you are referring to is a `<div>` not a `<p>`

Comment: Thanks, I tried all these recommendations, but none of them are working. In firebug, nonetheless, the margin at the bottom of the div where the image is is caused by a p element in some compiled css file.

Comment: I dont see any p tag in your website after or before the banner

Comment: I forced joomla to remove it because of the above issues I was having, though I did confirm that connexo's recommendation worked. Thanks